# Read HTML in c#

Tags: c#, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a specific number from a HTML page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710732/how-to-read-a-specific-number-from-a-html-page)

for example , if I wanted to set the ''Index value'' from this page: http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=Agfc5O8HHTlOLgX.q6V4HEtyzJpG;_ylu=X3oDMTFkdnZqMHBkBHBvcwMyBHNlYwN5ZmlNYXJrZXRTdW1tYXJ5RnJvbnRwYWdlBHNsawNzcHRzeA--?s=^GSPTSE

to a variable, how can I do that??

I am VERY NEW to programming, I would really appreciate if you explained every line. My point isnt to get it done, I want to understand it.

Thank you very much in advance!
I know I already posted this question but I forgot to mention I wanted to do this in c#.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It will help you parse html.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144188%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get the page HTML as a byte array and then parse it anyway you like

I would look for some data source (if available) that will provide the same info as a web API (xml) or RSS feed

Answer (score 1):

I agree the Html Agility Pack is a great way to do it, but for something down and dirty using just the .NET framework

```
using System.Net; // WebClient
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; // Regex

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string html = wc.DownloadString("<your url goes here>");
Regex regex = new Regex("<span id=\"yfs_l10_\\^gsptse\">([0-9\\.,]*)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
if (matches.Count > 0 && matches[0].Groups.Count > 0)
{
    // group 0 is entire string, group 1 is value matched in parenthesis
    string value = matches[0].Groups[1].Value; 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with `for something down and dirty using just the .NET framework`?

Comment: Without using external libraries and with six lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `HtmlAgilityPack` reference to your project.

Then, these two lines:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(
                    "http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=Agfc5O8HHTlOLgX.q6V4HEtyzJpG;_ylu=X3oDMTFkdnZqMHBkBHBvcwMyBHNlYwN5ZmlNYXJrZXRTdW1tYXJ5RnJvbnRwYWdlBHNsawNzcHRzeA--?s=^GSPTSE");
var indexValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='yfs_l10_^gsptse']").InnerText;
```

`HtmlAgilityPack` isn't difficult at all.

**As I always say:**
You should check that `SelectSingleNode` method is returning a valid node, otherwise you may get a `NullReferenceException` when calling `InnerText` property.

Comment: Mederos 
Cool thanks! It worked! Can you explain me how you got "//span[@id='yfs_l10_^gsptse']" ??